# Join attributes from point into lines (but only lines with certain attribute value)

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have point objects with attributes and line objects, where the attributes are missing.
The only connection between these geometries is an angle I calculated. (the labeling of the points has the same angle than the lines)

So I want to join the attributes from the points Into the line object, but only in the line object with the same angle value as the point. (There is a lot of overlap because I have over 10,000 line objects and each point belongs to a specific line)

My idea is it to generate a buffer around the points which hits the lines. Next step would be to check if the angle value matches before joining the attributes and this part is where I'm struggling.

Is there a possibility to do this?

I'm new to GIS.

Comment: What is the spatial relation between points and lines?

Comment: oh I forgot that, I wanted to do a buffer around the points which strikes the lines

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model here, so Questions should not only describe the task, they should also demonstrate work toward solving it (along with the problem encountered). Coding questions are expected to contain code. The answer to most "Is it possible" questions is "Yes" (so you want to make sure your question focuses on the *how* and/or "When I do *this* I get *that* error"). Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.